# How can I link a CSS file only on single posts?

Tags: posts, conditional-tags, template-tags

If I understand `is_single()` correctly, it's only supposed to return `true` when the current "post" (in a generic sense) is a literal post (i.e., it has a `post_type` of `post`), and that it will return `false` when the current "post" is a page, attachment, etc. This is what the Codex says:

```
is_single() returns true if any single post is being displayed
is_singular() returns true when any page, attachment, or single post is being displayed.
```

But when I try to link a CSS file only into a *post*, it's still included in attachment pages like `http://example.com/?attachment=123456789`. Here's the code I'm using:

```
<?php if ( is_single() ) { ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 4):

The Codex page for `is_single` should be updated, what you're seeing is correct behavior. According to the main [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Single_Post_Page) Codex page:

> **is_single()**
>
> When any single Post (**or attachment**, or custom Post Type) page is being displayed. (False for Pages)

You can exclude attachments by also checking `! is_attachment()`.

Also, you may want to move that code into an [enqueue style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) instead.

**EDIT-**

```
if ( is_single() && ! is_attachment() ) :
    echo 'is a single post and not an attachment';
endif;
```

Comment: daamn that sucks! So there's no way to exclude attachments and get css only on posts page? Thanks

Comment: @user20428 - there is, use is_attachment, see my edit.

Comment: You could also use `is_singular('post')`

Comment: fantastic! that works amazingly
thank you very much for your time and the help @milo!!!

Answer (score 2):

To specifically target single items of a particular post type use [`is_singular()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_singular):

```
if( is_singular( 'post' ) ) {
    // Only execute this block on a single page for a post with type 'post'
}
```